# migrating project contains maven from eclipse to android studio

Tags: maven, android-studio, eclipse-plugin

I found those lines with errors, in my android studio pom file.

```
<artifactId>maven-eclipse-plugin</artifactId>

<artifactId>maven-jarsigner-plugin</artifactId>
```

when I imported project contains those files to android studio.

moreover maven dependencies libraries are not found in my project and i cant import them.

i'm not familiar with maven project but it takes a place in my application.

those are the instructions that I found on this issue, but they don't include reference to my problem. 
http://www.trajano.net/2015/04/migrated-from-eclipse-to-android-studio/